# ASP.NET MC3 - single interface to create a record and the supporting records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the beginnings of an ASP.NET MVC3 application that is supposed to implement scheduling.  I have the following in my model:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public bool isDisabled { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("For Delivery")]
    public bool isDeliver { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TimeofDay> Times { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int weekday { get; set; }
}

public class TimeofDay
{
    [Key]
    public int TimeID {get;set;}
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

The model is supposed to accept 0 or more Time of Day entities that I pass by using JavaScript to create a new input field:

```
function createtimefield() {
    var TimeDiv = document.getElementById('timefields');
    var newDivInput = document.createElement("input");
    newDivInput.name = "Times";
    idText="Time" + GLOBAL_timeDivIdCount++;
    newDivInput.id = idText;
    newDivInput.value = "12:00 am";

    TimeDiv.appendChild(newDivInput);

}
```

My Controller will work file for accepting the data passed up until I add data to the time fields.  This is supposed to create new entities in the TimeofDay table that gets generated by the model, and link back to the the ScheduleID.  I don't want two interfaces to input this simple data, but can't seem to find the way to create both entities with MVC3 in a single action.  Anyone have any ideas?

Andrew

(Thank you for reading)

---

As requested the controller was:

```
public ActionResult Create(Schedule schedule, string[] schedTimes)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Schedule newschedule = db.Schedule.Add(schedule);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
         ......
     }
```

I now realize I need to create a view model that will encompass both my schedule class and an array of strings.  I will create the schedule and then iterate through the array of strings and create TimeofDay objects

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet for your `Controller` or make it more informative?

Comment: are you using entity framework or DAL directly in your controller?! This is not good as you create a dependency from the MVC / UI layer to the DAL. see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474267/mvc3-and-entity-framework/7474357#7474357

Comment: The first block of code is in my Model, as is the EF.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

for inputs to bind with times collection ur form fields need to have indexed names like

```
Times[0].TimeID // this would probably be hidden field
Times[0].Time
Times[1].TimeID
Times[1].Time
.
.
Times[n].TimeID
Times[n].Time
```

when you do this there might be other issues when deleting rows from the middle. there are lot of blog posts on this out there. Phil [haack's post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) is my favorite as it explains in very simple way how can you have non sequential indices for list binding. For more links please look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593669/asp-net-mvc3-can-you-post-and-bind-an-array-of-objects/6595624#6595624)

Comment: Yeah, that was what came to me last night in a dream: that I might need to reference it as an array.  I'll modify the Javascript as follows:  newDivInput.name = "Times["+GLOBAL_timeDivCount+"]";

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to create a view model to support this by extending my model as follows:

```
public class ScheduleCreate
{
    public Schedule schedule {get;set;}
    public string[] schedTimes {get;set}
}
```

I then modified my view by changing:

```
@model scheduler.Models.Schedule
```

to:

```
@model scheduler.Models.ScheduleCreate
```

I additionally changed all of the model.(parameter) to model.schedule.(parameter)

Then I changed my controller to:

```
public ActionResult Create(ScheduleCreate mod)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Schedule newschedule = db.Schedule.Add(mod.schedule);
            if (mod.schedTime != null)
            {
                foreach (string instanceTime in mod.schedTimes)
                {
               newschedule.Times.Add(new {Time = DateTime.Parse(instanceTime) }); // unteseted
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        PopulateDropDown();
        return View(mod.schedule);

}
```

Comment: turns out I should have used a constructor for the Schedule class that will instaciate the Times as a list.